# nginx proxy_pass for wordpress

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, wordpress

This is my weblog:

```
https://old-domain.com/blog
```

And I want to use `proxy_pass` to load my blog on another domain (`https://new-domain.com/blog`):

```
// config for new-domain.com
location /blog {
    proxy_pass https://old-domain.com/blog;
}
```

In wordpress admin, I set `https://new-domain.com/blog` for website address.

After it, if I open `https://new-domain.com/blog`, I get this error on browser:

This page isn’t working new-domain.com redirected you too many times.
How can I fix it?

Comment: There are many possible causes, so you need to use a tool like Wireshark to analyze those redirection responses (30x) first to see which one you hit.

Comment: Wireshark is not a good tool for this, it requires special effort to decrypt the HTTPS traffic. Browser developer tools are a better choice.

Comment: There may be a fight between what Nginx is sending to WordPress and where WordPress is redirecting to. Are you going to keep serving WordPress using the old domain?